# HTML5 Canvas: How to border a fillRect?

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

In HTML5, I want to make a `fillRect()` (with a white fill color) and a `border` (black). I don't want to use `strokeRect()` unless I can fill that later. I'm making a game where you click on squares and they change color (it's more complex than that but that's what this focuses on).

```
<canvas id="canvas1" width="400" height="300" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
    <script>
        var c=document.getElementById("canvas1");
        var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
        ctx.strokeStyle="rgba(0,0,0,1)";
        ctx.strokeRect(0,0,100,100);
    </script>
```

The border around the canvas is for reference.
I can use CSS too, but currently everything is in HTML.

Comment: as far as I know, there're just two ways how to do it, either draw the border around the canvas element, or draw the border inside the canvas using the strokeRect().  I still don't understand though, why you can't use neither of these options.

Comment: Why would you not use fillRect followed by strokeRect? It does exactly what you're asking for.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Work out the position you want to draw the square with the width and height. Once you have done that simply draw a bigger square first which has wider by 2 and higher by 2 but with the same center point. So you draw a square which is bigger and then you draw the normal square on top, this then gives you the illusion of the square has a border

HTML

```
<canvas id="canvas1" width="400" height="300" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
```

CSS

```
#canvas1{
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

Javascript

```
var c=document.getElementById("canvas1");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");

var rectXPos = 50;
var rectYPos = 50;
var rectWidth = 100;
var rectHeight = 100;

drawBorder(rectXPos, rectYPos, rectWidth, rectHeight)

ctx.fillStyle='#FFF';
ctx.fillRect(rectXPos, rectYPos, rectWidth, rectHeight);

function drawBorder(xPos, yPos, width, height, thickness = 1)
{
  ctx.fillStyle='#000';
  ctx.fillRect(xPos - (thickness), yPos - (thickness), width + (thickness * 2), height + (thickness * 2));
}
```

jsfiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/jxgw19sh/2/

-- Update --

Add an extra parameter to `drawBorder` called `thickness` the default value is 1 but you can provide any other number for `thickness` into the function and it will use value instead of 1.

Comment: Calling strokeRect would avoid the position recalculations.

Answer (score 28):

you can not fill it later without a library. If you want to change something simply redraw.
You can use something like that:

```
ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
var fillRect = false;
ctx.rect(20, 20, 150, 100);
if (fillRect) {
  ctx.fill();
}
ctx.stroke();
```

it will draw only the border, if you change `fillRect` to `true` it will be filled. You can update your canvas on every `requestAnimationFrame`.

But maybe you want to use a library like paper.js. It makes things like clicking on objects much easier and it abstracts draws on canvas to objects you create once and update later, like what you asked for.

Comment: Add `ctx.beginPath()` before and `ctx.closePath()` after this code. Otherwise you will see some fun, but probably undesired behaviour.

Answer (score 7):

### I tried on my own and it looks like this:

```
var x = 100;
var y = 100;
var width = 50;
var height = 50;

var borderWidth = 5;   
var offset = borderWidth * 2;

c.beginPath();
c.fillStyle = 'black';
c.fillRect( x - borderWidth, y -borderWidth, width + offset, height + offset);
c.fillStyle = 'green';
c.fillRect( x, y, width, height);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation about the code.

Comment: @ppwater i thought about doing it, but the code looks pretty much self-explanatory. In any case i'll add it