# How to make this draw zoomable

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

This is my javascript and html until now. Please can someone help me find a way to make this rect zoomable on mousewheel

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var width = 50;
var height = 35;
var $width = document.getElementById('width');
var $height = document.getElementById('height')

$width.value = width;
$height.value = height;

$width.addEventListener("keyup", function () {
    width = this.value;
    draw();
}, false);

$height.addEventListener("keyup", function () {
    height = this.value;
    draw();
}, false);

function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillRect(40, 40, width, height);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `CSS Transform Property` called `scale` just like that !

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
     canvas.addEventListener("dblclick", function(){
      this.style.transform="scale(1.5)";
     });
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var width = 50;
var height = 35;
var $width = document.getElementById('width');
var $height = document.getElementById('height');

function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillRect(40, 40, width, height);
}
draw();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Cool! i got a few more questions if u dont mind. First: how can i use that to zoom IN and OUT like on mousewheel the square comes closer and then it gets more distant if that what the user wanted. Second: How can a draw only the ''borders'' without filling the square. Thanks!!!

Comment: Here's an example to draw border without filling the square [Draw Border](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38174937/11523447).
Also in this link [MouseWheel Event](https://www.sitepoint.com/html5-javascript-mouse-wheel/) you can understand how MouseWheel Event works!

Enjoy! if you need help to understand codes tell me !